# How do I lowercase a string and also change space into underscore in python?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I change a string into lowercase and change space into an underscore in python?

For example, I have a string which `Ground Improvement`

I want it to be `ground_improvement`

For now, I know how to that manually use `replace`.

```
df['type'] = df['type'].replace('Ground Improvement', 'ground_improvement')
```

But it's only for ground improvement, I want to make some automation so if there comes any string into the `type` column, the script will always change into the format I want.

Thankyou.

Comment: Please post sample input data with expected output for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `lower` and `replace` on whitespace

```
df['type'] = df['type'].str.replace(' ','_').str.lower()
```

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['Ground Improvement']})
df
```

looks like this

```
    type
0   Ground Improvement
```

output

```
    type
0   ground_improvement
```

Answer (score 0):

Just two lines: -

```
s = "Ground Improvement"
s = str.lower() # Converts the entire string to lower case
s = str.replace(' ', '_') # Replaces the spaces with _
```

And There you have `ground_improvement` stored in `s`!